# is there a way to list files based on LastWriteAccess date?

Tags: powershell

my first approach was:
`gci -File | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -eq "3/25/2021"}`
but this doesn't return anything

conversely with `-gt` and `-lt` operators it appears to work

```
gci | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt "3/24/2021" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt "3/26/2021"}

    Directory: C:\logs

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           24/3/2021  7:42 PM        1048804 fdm.1
-a---           24/3/2021  7:45 AM        1048617 hostd-probe.1
-a---           25/3/2021 10:27 AM          24246 usb.log
```

What I'm looking is to list files on a specific `LastWriteAccess` date. I haven't used `.addDays()` method because I'll periodically check same files on the specific dates, thus, having a static date would be more convenient instead of changing the `.addDays()` value

Comment: Welcome @mich_a! Might I suggest to avoid alias when posting questions? While aliases are a nice shortcut they tend make it more difficult to read and debug. As for you question the problem is when you use "3/26/2021"  that is a string in PowerShell. You should use (get-date 3/23/2021) which returns a date time object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LastWriteTime` is a specific date and *time*. You're comparing equality to just a date, so you need to reference that property

```
gci -File | ? {$_.LastWriteTime.date -eq "3/25/2021"}
```

Also, if this is a script that is going to be used by others or in production, it's best not to use aliases.

```
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.date -eq "3/25/2021"}
```

Comment: thank you @Doug Mauer. It feels like it was just under my nose.:)

Comment: @mich_a You may also consider accepting this as the answer by clicking the checkmark. That way other readers can easily find the solution.